# Is it possible to have a documentation only file with Haddock?

Tags: haskell, documentation, haddock

I'm writing a documentation for a Haskell module with great number of tests and examples. This make my source file very long (3000 lines).

My idea is to make a second source file (*.hs) with my full examples and only documentation (no functions definitions). But when I write my documentation, I can't have my headers appear correctly:

```
module JeanJouX.Numeric.Tests (
    -- | Introduction to my module
    --
    -- * Section 1
    -- ** Sub section 1
    -- doc text
    -- ...
    -- * Section 2
    -- ** Sub section 1
    --
```

But when I break my source like this :

```
module JeanJouX.Numeric.Tests (
    -- | Introduction to my module
    --

    -- * Section 1
    -- ** Sub section 1
    -- doc text
    -- ...
    -- * Section 2
    -- ** Sub section 1
    --
```

My documentation text doesn't appear (I think Haddock is waiting for a function export).

**Is it possible to make a Haskell source file with documentation *only* this way ?**

**Is there a better way to do it ?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There exist packages with documentation-only modules. [pipes](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-4.3.13/docs/Pipes-Tutorial.html) and [generic-random](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/generic-random-1.3.0.1/docs/Generic-Random-Tutorial.html) for example.

Two relevant haddock features regarding organizing things in sections are [named chunks](https://haskell-haddock.readthedocs.io/en/latest/markup.html#named-chunks) and [markup for headings](https://haskell-haddock.readthedocs.io/en/latest/markup.html#headings) which is (confusingly) different from the `* Section` syntax.

```hs
-- | Package description
--
-- = Introduction
--
-- == Subsection Title
--
-- Text.

module MyModule
  ( -- * Section 1
    -- $qsdf
  ) where

-- $qsdf
-- More text.
--
-- == SubSection Title
--
-- etc.
```

It is a bit weird that `= XYZ` and `* XYZ` render differently even though they otherwise both boil down to `<h1>XYZ</h1>` in HTML, but you can keep everything uniform by sticking to one style, either above the `module` line (with `= XYZ` titles) or below (with `* XYZ` titles).